# jQuery fallback link reloads the page instead

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks

Currently, if the jQuery script cannot be loaded, SE displays a banner on the top of the page with a link saying "Retry using another source". However, this link, when clicked, will add the "use jquery fallback" cookie and redirect you to the main page. This can be frustrating because I have to re-enter the page url(or click the back button AND force a refresh because browsers can cache past pages) to return to the page. IIRC it redirects to a "jQuery cookie-adding page", and the proposed fix is to add a `?returnUrl=blahblahblah` and make that page redirect you to the page you were on.